# Using System properties in a Gradle build script

Tags: properties, gradle

This should be the simplest of questions but I am having a problem accessing System variable from a Gradle test task.  There must be a typo in [what I am doing](https://github.com/djangofan/GradleProps) since I am convinced this syntax is correct but it doesn't work.  I am hoping someone can help me identify the problem with this code snippet below?

```
// my gradle build says the following line is a deprecated method    
//systemProperties = System.getProperties()

// this line always returns 1 on a multiprocessor system
println 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS is ' +
     System.getProperty( "NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS", "1" )

// this line also always returns the default for TMP var
println 'TMP is ' + System.getProperty( "TMP", "C:\\Temp" )
```

NOTE: I also asked [the question here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_should_i_be_handling_passing_system_properties_from_gradle_to_my_tests) but since its a closed thread I am unsure if I will get an answer there.  Also, I have [read the doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html) thoroughly but it didn't help.

I tried these and they also fail:

```
test {
    println ""
    ENV = System.getProperties()
    println "TMP is " + ENV['TMP']
    println ""
}

task testa(Type:Test) { 
    println ""
    println "HOMEPATH = " + System.getProperty( "HOMEPATH", "defaultpath" )
    println "TMP = " + System.getProperty( "TMP", "defaulttmp" )
    println ""
}

task testb(Type:Test) {
    println ""
    println "HOMEPATH = " + System.properties['HOMEPATH']
    println "TMP = " + System.properties['TMP']
    println ""
}

task testc(Type:Test) {
    // pass a arg to this test like -PMYARG=anything
    println ""
    println "Parg = " + System.properties['MYARG']
    println ""
}

testWorks {
    println ""
    ENV['ok'] = "good to go"
    println "this test is " + ENV['ok']
    println ""
}
```

Comment: are you trying to access environment variables or are you trying to access jvm system properties?

Comment: @erdi - jvm system properties

Comment: then Peter seems to point you in the right direction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make the Gradle JVM's system properties available to tests, you can do:

```
test {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

Or, if you have declared additional `Test` tasks:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

Comment: I added a "testd" to my project (referenced in my question above) but after adding that test, using your suggestion, it did not seem to work.  I got this error, which I already mentioned in my question:  "Deprecated dynamic property: "systemProperties" on "task ':testd'", value: "{java.vendor=Oracle Co...".   To reproduce this error, you can download my project from GitHub.

Comment: It's `type: Test`, not `Type: Test`.

Comment: Ok, I altered my project on GitHub and used your advice and still cannot get it to work.  The minute I enable the line you suggest above, I get an exception seen here: https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5430278  .  If I comment that one line it all works.  So, I am still unable to get it to work.  It shouldn't be this difficult for something so simple.  With Maven, I have no such trouble.

Comment: `Deprecated dynamic property: "systemProperties"` is not an exception, it's a deprecation warning. It works anyway. Still I wonder where it comes from and what to use instead...

Comment: Your problem sounds different. The deprecation warning means that an  `systemProperties` property is introduced on an object that does *not* define such a property (rather than a `Test` task), without explicitly saying that this is desired (vs. configuring an existing property). This is a bug in the build code, and won't have any effect on tests. In Gradle 2.0 (next after 1.12), this will cause the build to fail.

Comment: Gradle 2.0 just came out.  I tried this again, just taking a 'pure Groovy' approach within my test block, and am not having any problems this time.  Thanks Peter.  I updated my Github project.